# R Fill in empty cells after binning with cut() function

Tags: r, cut, binning

I am using the cut() function to bin a vector integergers. The procedure works well and provides the number of integers that fall into each bin, however for bins without a number, it isn't listed. I would like to fill these in such that there is a cell for each bin and for bins without numbers, it fills them in with 0. For example:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE) 
bins <- cut(x, breaks = 4, labels =FALSE)
bins_tab <- table(bins)
bins_tab
```

This gives:

```
bins
 1  3  4 
33 34 33
```

I would like to fill in 2 with a 0 such that the output is:

```
 bins
 1  2  3  4 
33  0 34 33
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: +1 for input data/desired output/what you tried to do. Nice compact question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
table( cut( x , breaks = 4 , labels = 1:4 ) )

# 1  2  3  4 
#33  0 34 33
```

i.e. make sure there is a label for the empty factor level.

Comment: That works perfectly - forcing the labels fills in the empty bins. Thanks!